# python cannot find module that is installed on windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.4

I have installed the requests module

```
C:\Python34\Scripts\easy_install.exe requests
```

i got to the folder location

```
C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\requests-2.13.0-py3.4.egg\requests
```

I have a path variable in system

```
C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages
```

yet when i run my script

```
C:\Users\beast\Desktop>update.py
```

I get the error No module named 'requests'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\beast\Desktop\plex_playlist_update.py", line 17, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

I tried installing using pip just in case

```
python -m pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\python34\lib\site-packages\requests-2.13.0-py3.4.egg
```

I am new to python and I cant find an answer anywhere.

UPDATE:

I found a command to check my python search location.

```
C:\Users\beast\Desktop>python -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages())"
['C:\\Python34', 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']
```

I think it has to do with C:\Python34 vs C:\python34?  How do i check or fix this?

Comment: What happens when you run `python update.py`?

Comment: python: can't open file 'update.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Did you call it from the right directory?

Comment: You have "a path variable in system `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages`"? That makes no sense. Start by reading sections 1 and 3 of the [setup and usage docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/using/index.html). It looks like you may have multiple Python installations, and .py files are currently associated with another installation. Add a line that prints `sys.executable` to see which Python you're running.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is maybe because of the different versions of python installed.
If you are a Windows user, you can go to Path in Environment variables and remove the paths to unnecessary versions of python (if any). Modules installed for one version of python won't work in another version.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up going with python environment. Per python documentation it is the way to go anyway.  The below command are run on the root folder of the python app.

`py -m venv env`
then
`./env/Scripts/activate`

I then ran my pip upgrade and everything is working.  Obviously this did not fix it computer wide.  just for my python app.  But from documentation this is better because of version control of the whole enviroment.

This creates a "env" folder at the root which will have all the packages installed.  Need to install all requirements again or use the requirements.txt file.